# How can I load historic data into a hypertable, and have the aggregate views pick it up

Tags: timescaledb

I have a hypertable (Event) and an associated continuous aggregate view (Daily Events)

In my testing I want to load a years worth of data historically, and have the aggregate view be refreshed to have that data.

What is the right incantation to be able to achieve that.

Here is the view and the settings ...
[image]

---

Note: On Timescale 1.7, on PG 12

Comment: I used to change the max_interval, and manually run REFRESH MATERIALIZED

Comment: Since you have set the refresh interval to 1 hour, it will take an hour before it is updated. You can trigger an update using REFRESH MATERIALIZE VIEW as you did.